# Typescript interface property to string

Tags: javascript, typescript

### Question/Answer - Update 2021

*This questions was asked **6 years ago**, and I had very little understanding of Typescript!
I don't want to remove it because there are still some people reading this post.*

If you want the type of a variable to be a property of another one, you can use `keyof`.

Example:

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const nameProperty: keyof User = 'name'; // ok
const ageProperty: keyof User = 'age'; // ok
const emailProperty: keyof User = 'email'; // not ok
```

If you want a method that takes a parameter which is a property of another parameter you can use generics to link both types together.

Example using generics + `keyof`:

```
const foo = <TObject extends object>(
    object: TObject,
    property: keyof TObject
) => {
    // You can use object[property] here
};

foo({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'a'); // ok
foo({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'b'); // ok
foo({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'c'); // not ok
```

Example using generics + `Record`:

```
const foo = <TKey extends string>(
    object: Record<TKey, unknown>,
    property: TKey
) => {
    // You can use object[property] here
};

foo({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'a'); // ok
foo({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'b'); // ok
foo({ a: 1, b: 2 }, 'c'); // not ok
```

**Don't use this question answers please!** *Typescript will automatically tell you that there is an error if you rename the property at some point.*

---

### Original question (2014)

**Objective**

I have an interface TypeScript :

```
interface IInterface{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

I have some methods which take in entry the name of a property (string).

**Ex** :

```
var methodX = ( property: string, object: any ) => {
    // use object[property]
};
```

My problem is that when i call `methodX`, I have to write the property name in string.

**Ex :** `methodX("name", objectX);` *where objectX implements IInterface*

But this is **BAD** : If i rename a property (let's say i want to rename `name` to `lastname`) i will have to update manually all my code.

And I don't want this dependency.

As typescript interfaces have no JS implementations, I don't see how I could not use string.

I want to have something like : `methodX(IInterface.name.propertytoString(), objectX);`

I'm pretty new to JS, do you see an alternative ?

**(Optional) More details :** Why do I need to pass properties as parameter, and why I don't use a generic method ?

I use methods that link data :

```
linkData = <TA, TB>(
    inputList: TA[],
    inputId: string,
    inputPlace: string,
    outputList: TB[],
    outputId: string ) => {

    var mapDestinationItemId: any = {};
    var i: number;
    for ( i = 0; i < outputList.length; ++i ) {
        mapDestinationItemId[outputList[i][outputId]] = outputList[i];
    }

    var itemDestination, itemSource;
    for ( i = 0; i < inputList.length; ++i ) {
        itemDestination = inputList[i];
        itemSource = mapDestinationItemId[itemDestination[inputId]];
        if ( itemSource ) {
            itemDestination[inputPlace] = itemSource;
        }
    }
};
```

But TA and TB can have a lot of different ids. So i don't see how to make it more generic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update 2019: This answer is outdated, please look at the update added directly into the question.**

---

**basarat** answer is a good idea, but it doesn't work with interfaces.

You **can't** write `methodX(interfacePropertyToString(()=>interfaceX.porpertyname), objectX)` because `interfaceX` is not an object.

*Interfaces are abstractions and they are used only for TypeScript, they doesn't exist in Javascript.*

But thanks to his answer i found out the solution : **using a parameter in the method**.

Finally we have :

```
    interfacePropertyToString = ( property: (object: any) => void ) => {
        var chaine = property.toString();
        var arr = chaine.match( /[\s\S]*{[\s\S]*\.([^\.; ]*)[ ;\n]*}/ );
        return arr[1];
    };
```

We have to use `[\s\S]` to be able to match on multilines because Typescript convert `(object: Interface) => {object.code;}` to a multiline function.

Now you can use it as you want :

```
        interfacePropertyToString(( o: Interface ) => { o.interfaceProperty});
        interfacePropertyToString( function ( o: Interface  ) { o.interfaceProperty});
```

Comment: Great answer! Could you please explain a little about how TypeScript deals with interfaces defined by the user and what does it compile them into? Because I didn't find much about this.
Thanks!

Comment: Also, can you think of any way to extract all properties of an interface this way? Thanks!

Comment: @radu-matei A TypeScript interface does not transpile into Javascript. It simply does not exist in Javascript.

Comment: Getting this error: 
Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')

Comment: Not sure where you guys got that regex, but based on the code and assuming a format like this: `o => o.SomeProperty` you'd need to update the regex like so `[a-zA-Z]+\s=>\s[a-zA-Z]+\.([A-Za-z0-9]+)` and then use `return arr[2]`. The regex basically puts a group around the prop name so that we can pull it out of `arr`

Answer (score 3):

I've changed **basarat** code a little bit, so we can use it as generic:

```
const P = <T>( property: (object: T) => void ) => {
    const chaine = property.toString();
    const arr = chaine.match( /[\s\S]*{[\s\S]*\.([^\.; ]*)[ ;\n]*}/ );
    return arr[1];
};
```

And example usage:

```
console.log(P<MyInterface>(p => p.propertyName));
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer!

Answer (score 3):

For browsers that support the Proxy class:

```
function propToString<T>(obj?: T): T {
  return new Proxy({}, {
    get({}, prop) {
      return prop;
    }
  }) as T;
}

class Foo {
  bar: string;
  fooBar: string;
}

console.log(propToString<Foo>().bar, propToString(new Foo()).fooBar);
// Prints: bar fooBar

// Cache the values for improved performance:
const Foo_bar = propToString<Foo>().bar;
```

Comment: This is excellent.  `get` should probably not take an empty object, and should instead take a param name. Code quality tools can flag the empty destructure as a bug.  `_` could be used to signify the parameter is unimportant.  `get(_, prop)....`

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function to parse the body of a function to find the name e.g.:

```
methodX(getName(()=>something.name), objectX)
```

Where `getName` will do a `toString` on the function body to get a string of the form `"function(){return something.name}"` and then parse it to get `"name"`.

Note: however this has a tendency to break depending upon how you minify it.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related problem - how to get/set a value to a property path. I wrote two classes for that:

```
export class PropertyPath {
    static paths = new Map<string, PropertyPath>()

    static get<T, P>(lambda: (prop:T) => P) : PropertyPath {
        const funcBody = lambda.toString();
        var ret : PropertyPath = this.paths[funcBody];
        if (!ret) {
            const matches = funcBody.match( /(?:return[\s]+)(?:\w+\.)((?:\.?\w+)+)/ ); //first prop ignores
            var path = matches[1];
            ret = new PropertyPath(path.split("."));
            this.paths[funcBody] = ret;
        }
        return ret;
    };

    path : Array<string>

    constructor(path : Array<string>) {
        this.path = path
    }

    getValue( context : any) {
        const me = this;
        var v : any;
        return this.path.reduce( (previous, current, i, path) => {
            try {
                return previous[current];
            }
            catch (e) {
                throw {
                    message : `Error getting value by path. Path: '${path.join(".")}'. Token: '${current}'(${i})`,
                    innerException: e
                };
            }
        }, context)
    }

    setValue( context : any, value : any) {
        const me = this;
        var v : any;
        this.path.reduce( (previous, current, i, path) => {
            try {
                if (i == path.length - 1) {
                    previous[current] = value
                }
                return previous[current];
            }
            catch (e) {
                throw {
                    message : `Error setting value by path. Path: '${path.join(".")}'. Token: '${current}'(${i}). Value: ${value}`,
                    innerException: e
                };
            }
        }, context)
    }

}
```

Example of usage:

```
var p = PropertyPath.get((data:Data) => data.person.middleName)
var v = p.getValue(data)
p.setValue(data, newValue)
```

---

Some sugar over it:

```
export class PropertyPathContexted {

    static get<T, P>(obj : T, lambda: (prop:T) => P) : PropertyPathContexted {
        return new PropertyPathContexted(obj, PropertyPath.get(lambda));
    };

    context: any
    propertyPath: PropertyPath

    constructor(context: any, propertyPath: PropertyPath) {
        this.context = context
        this.propertyPath = propertyPath
    }

    getValue = () => this.propertyPath.getValue(this.context)

    setValue = ( value : any) => {this.propertyPath.setValue(this.context, value) }

}
```

And usage:

```
var p = PropertyPathContexted.get(data, () => data.person.middleName)
var v = p.getValue()
p.setValue("lala")
```

---

I find the the latest quite convenient in two-way databinding in React:

```
var valueLink = function<T, P>( context: T, lambda: (prop:T) => P) {
    var p = PropertyPathContexted.get(context, lambda);
    return {
        value: p.getValue(),
        requestChange: (newValue) => {
            p.setValue(newValue);
        }
    }
};

render() {
   var data = getSomeData()
   //...
   return (
       //...
       <input name='person.surnames' placeholder='Surnames' valueLink={valueLink(data, () => data.person.surnames)}/>
       //...
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to validate the strings you can create a new `type` based on `keyof` from the `interface`. If you have an object you can use `keyof typeof` object.

Example for language files:

localizationService.ts

```
import svSE from './languages/sv-SE';
import enUS from './languages/en-US';
import arSA from './languages/ar-SA';
import { ILanguageStrings } from './ILanguageStrings';

/*
If more languages are added this could be changed to:
    "sv-SE": svSE,
    "en-US": enUS,
    "ar-SA": arSA
*/

export const messages = {
    "sv": svSE,
    "en": enUS,
    "ar": arSA
};

//Identical types
export type IntlMessageID = keyof typeof messages.en;
export type IntlMessageID2 = keyof ILanguageStrings;
```

[image]

ILanguageStrings.ts

```
export interface ILanguageStrings {
    appName: string
    narration: string
    language: string
    "app.example-with-special-charactes": string
}
```

en-US.ts

```
import { ILanguageStrings } from '../ILanguageStrings';

const language: ILanguageStrings = {
    appName: "App Eng",
    narration: "Narration",
    language: "Language",
    "app.example-with-special-charactes": "Learn React."
}

export default language;
```